# Android test annotations with Robotium

Tags: android, robotium

I'm currently building an app in Android, and using Robotium to do functional tests (By the way, don't use Robotium on anything less that Android 1.6, it is way too buggy).

Some of these tests have a random tendency to fail, mainly Robotium missing a text field, or timing out, not reading text.  I am trying to use the `@FlakyTest` annotation, so they will run two or three times before throwing out a failed test error.  However, the annotation is not working, the tests do not re-run after a failure.

Here is how I am using the annotation:

```
public class ClassName extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<HomeActivity>{

        @LargeTest
        @FlakyTest(tolerance=3)
        public void testMethod(){

        //Here I run my roboitium scripts.

        }
}
```

Then I run it from the command line:

> adb shell am instrument -w com.jayway.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner

Neither eclipse nor the command line execution of the tests takes into account the flaky test annotation.  Does anyone see an error with how I am trying to apply `@FlakyTest`?

Comment: you might want to ask this on the robotium mailing list..

Answer (score 3):

I can't see any issue with your use of the `@FlakyTest` annotation.

I put together a quick test case to test @FlakyTest and Robotium (v2.2):

```
public class FlakyTestCase extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<Main> {

private static int count = 0;
private Solo solo;

public FlakyTestCase() {
    super("com.stackoverflow.example", Main.class);
}

@Override
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
}

@LargeTest
@FlakyTest(tolerance=3)
public void testFlaky(){
    Log.e("FlakeyTestCase", "Execution Count:" + ++count);

    solo.assertCurrentActivity(null,Main.class);
    solo.clickOnText("Doesn't Exist");

    Log.e("FlakeyTestCase", "Shouldn't make it here");
}
}
```

LogCat showed the following messages:

```
Execution Count: 1
Execution Count: 2
Execution Count: 3
```

So the `@FlakyTest` annotation was definitely being invoked. The (final) failure of the test was shown as:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: The text: Doesn't Exist is not found!
```

And the message `"Shouldn't make it here"` was never logged.

So as far as I can see, there is no issue with how you've declared your annotation or any problems with `@FlakyTest` and Robotium, v2.2 anyway.

Perhaps there is an issue with another part of your test code?

Comment: You should use the latest version of Robotium (5.1)

Answer (score 3):

In general, when writing tests for Android (with or without Robotium) you have to be much more careful. You can't just say "is this visible". You need to wrap everything in a "wait for" cycle, so would say "wait for this to be visible". This is particularly a problem when running in the emulators, because sometimes things take long without any good reason. Without the waiting cycles, you will never have a consistent run. We have a few hundred tests and we have never needed to use the FlakyTest annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Robotium missing a text field, or timing out, not reading text means
We have to check clearly if the text or any existed on the screen then only need to perform the actions like

```
if(solo.searchText("Doesn't Exist", true){
solo.clickOnText("Doesn't Exist");
}
```

Similar if any components like button or others we can achieve this by above logic.

Answer (score -3):

Add this to your code:

```
import android.util.Log;
```